AGORA: Can't load device of app (Flutter) when calling video between app & web
Here's my config and log
let client = AgoraRTC.createClient({
    mode: 'rtc',
    codec: "h264",
    role: 'host'
})

//#2
let config = {
    appid: '{{ $agora_chat->appid }}',
    token: '{{ $agora_chat->token }}',
    uid: '{{ $agora_chat->uid }}',
    channel: '{{ $agora_chat->channel }}',
}

//#3 - Setting tracks for when user joins
let localTracks = {
    audioTrack: null,
    videoTrack: null
}

//#4 - Want to hold state for users audio and video so user can mute and hide
let localTrackState = {
    audioTrackMuted: false,
    videoTrackMuted: false
}

My problem is when calling between web and web is fine, but app and web then only the app can receive the device from web, the web can't receive device from app.
